# How to sort files separately without merging?

Tags: files, sort, stdout

File1:

```
Brazil
New Zealand
Argentina
Uruguay
```

File2:

```
Chile
Russia
Latvia
Switzerland
```

I realize that the command

```
sort -n File1 File2
```

will sort all the files merged together and display it in stdout.

But I only want to sort the files individually and not together.

Is there a 1 line bash command that sort both at the same time and display it's contents separately in stdout?

Something that'd give me stdout of:

```
File 1:
Argentina
Brazil
New Zealand
Uruguay

File 2:
Chile
Latvia
Russia
Switzerland
```

Comment: sort file1; echo; sort file2

Comment: Note that the `-n` option means to do a numeric sort which is irrelevant for text even if it works.

Answer (score 5):

For two files, you can just run two commands:

```
echo File 1: ; sort File1 ; echo File2: ; sort File2
```

For more files, a loop might be more suitable:

```
for file in *.txt ; do echo "$file" ; sort "$file" ; done
```