# How to extract first name in Alphabetical order from multiple files

Tags: bash, sort, tail

Say I have

File1:

```
Aaron
Vernon
Troy
Roy
```

File2:

```
Jason
Derek
Mariano
Alex
```

I want to display:

```
File1: Aaron
File2: Alex
```

What would be a single line bash command that could do both?

I was thinking of using sort and then tail -1, but that only extracts it from 1 file at a time.

Comment: Do you sometimes go by [kylo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/286293/117549)?

Comment: Haha yes, this question is a tad bit different though.

Comment: `grep -H . File1 | sort | head -n 1; grep -H . File2 | sort | head -n 1`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk (which has a built in array sorting function `asort`) you could do

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE{delete a}; 
  {a[FNR]=$0}; 
  ENDFILE{asort(a); print FILENAME": "a[1];}
' File1 File2
File1: Aaron
File2: Alex
```

You can write it in a single line if you wish

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{delete a}; {a[FNR]=$0}; ENDFILE{asort(a); print FILENAME": "a[1];}' File1 File2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in File* ; do
  printf "%s: %s\n" "$f" $(sort "$f" | head -n 1)
done
```

Output:

```
File1: Aaron
File2: Alex
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to achieve your goal.

```
grep . File1 File2|sort -k 2,2 -t:|sed 's/:/: /g'
File1: Aaron
File2: Alex
File2: Derek
File2: Jason
File2: Mariano
File1: Roy
File1: Troy
File1: Vernon
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I needed. Out of curiosity how does sed work with those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For the original question (one line from each file, not all lines sorted as you now say you 'needed'), and efficient if the files are large (especially larger than fits in memory), if you have non-ancient GNU awk (most Linuxes and some other systems with `bash`):

```
[g]awk -vx= 'FNR==1||$0<x {x=$0""} ENDFILE {print FILENAME": "x}' file1 file2 ...
```

With non-GNU awk (or ancient gawk) you can still do it but it's a little clumsier:

```
[*]awk -vx= 'FNR==1&&NR!=1 {print f": "x} FNR==1||$0<x {f=FILENAME;x=$0""} END {if(NR) print f": "x}' file1 file2 ...
```